# Google Place Api Key return only nearby cities

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I am using google place api key for search cites but it gives only nearby cities.
Here is the code

```
NSString *GoogleURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/cities/json"];
    NSDictionary *param = @{@"location":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",sharedManager.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,sharedManager.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude],
                            @"radius":@(20000),
                            @"name":searchController.searchBar.text,
                            @"key":GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY
                            };
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager=[[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
    [manager GET:GoogleURL parameters:param progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        if ([[responseObject objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
            self.resultsArray = [SWGooglePlace getLocationForApp:[responseObject objectForKey:@"results"]];     
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

For example if I am living in Newyork and I type the city than no result found. Only places shown within the newyork city.

Comment: google place api is used for searching places.... then you have to filter cities from places results in another array

Comment: But I didn't get the cities in response.

Comment: yes, google place api only gives you nearby places then you have to reverse geocode these places to get latitude,longitude,city,country data from these places

Comment: is there any api to get the cities and place at a time?

Answer (score 0):

when you will get nearby places from google places api then to find there latitude,longitude,city,country, you have to user this method of CLGeocoder

```
    CLGeocoder *geocode = [CLGeocoder new];

    [_geoCoder geocodeAddressString:yourstring completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",placemarks[0]);

    }];
```

here in address string you have to pass place api formatted string result which will provide you whole data of that place then you can extract a particular data from results like city or country.